# Import a static HTML website to Django CMS

Tags: html, django, django-cms

I have designed and coded a website (with bootstrap 4) and now I would like to import it in Django CMS so the client can edit the content.

Any tips or guide that helps me to achieve this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it into a template and import the information itself separately. Add new template to settings.py.

If your client already has a basic template that you're editing you may simply edit his existing files and CSS. Alternatively, you may also download/import an existing template and use it as your base for editing.

The template itself will look something like this: default template: base.html,

```
{% load i18n %}
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Title Here{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

@A-creative At first you should copy Bootstrap 4 static files (css and js) into your "projectname/appname/static" dir, run "python manage.py collectstatic" and then just copy your Bootstrap-ready html into the cms using Style, Text and Snippet plugin fields (Admin > Create new page > Edit > Add plugin/block > ...). You should do it page by page.

I doubt there is a shorter way... Yeap, and your should use a standard minimalistic template as mentioned by @Patriot to avoid dealing with template issues and plugin / html issues at the same time.